# How to display the original raw Html code?

Tags: jquery, html, character-encoding

I have the opposite of what most are asking. I want to display the original Html character code instead of displaying its glyph.

I have a table of emojis using the latest Unicode codes.  For example, 😀 😇 are written in the page as `&#x1f600;` and `&#1f607;`.  I am doing a quick reference utility, so that when I click one of them, I want to show the code of the graphic.  Unfortunately, if I push the character value to an element's innerText or innerHTML, it always show the glyph. How do I display a value of `&#1f600;` in its literal form of `&#1f600;` and not 😀

---

Thanks for all the helpful answers. I tried using `<code>` and `<pre>` but they didn't work for me.  I used jQuery to select a `<code>` element and set its `text` to `&#x1f600;`.  The graphic is shown instead of the literal code characters. Perhaps I am using the wrong property or function. Or should I be not using jQuery at all?

My code is:

```
<script>
  $('.emoji').click( function() {
     $('#selected').text(this.innerText);
  });
</script>

<div class='emoji'>&#x1f600;</div> 
<div class='emoji'>&#x1f607;</div>

<code id='selected'></code>
```

Comment: Can the person downvoting all the answers please explain why? they all seem to work for me. It'd be helpful to explain what your issue is

Comment: Do you mean that you want to literally convert an existing character in the HTML to its character reference code, or are you asking how to display the values when you're building the table? All the answers so far are for the latter case, and none for the former.

Comment: Please share your actual code, rather than just a description.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML-encoding in JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to save the character code to a data attribute and pull it from there.

```js
  $('.emoji').click( function() {
     $('#selected').text("&#x"+$(this).data('code')+";");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='emoji' data-code="1f600">&#x1f600;</div> 
<div class='emoji' data-code="1f607">&#x1f607;</div>

<code id='selected'></code>
```

Comment: This is the conclusion I was getting to - didn't seem to be an easy way to extract the original out

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like:

```
&amp;#x1f600;
```

See this code pen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbgKpw

Comment: It seems someone is trigger happy, there are downvotes all around.

Comment: No worries, only recently started answering more, was confused as to why, that's all...

Answer (score 1):

In case you encode only the ampersand & and it will show what you want:

```
&amp;#x1f607;&#x1f607;
```

&#x1f607;   😇

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mbdpzdq/

```
<xmp>
    &#x1f600;
</xmp>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the `<xmp>` element is deprecated.

Comment: yes, this is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)

Comment: Ah, did not know. Thanks :)